# Setting Django on Shared Host with FastCGI

Tags: django, apache, shared-hosting, fastcgi

I know this might be a question often asked, but I tried my best for almost a day to launch my first django website with no results, so please anyone experienced with shared hosting and django to help. Here is any relevant info:
python 2.6 installed on the remote machine at $HOME/.local/lib/
flup and django at same place, all is done by setup.py install --user.
my django project file structure:

```
$HOME/
    projects/django/bw_python/
                              manage.py
                              bw_python/
                                        __init__.py
                                        settings.py
                                        urls.py
                                        wsgi.py
                              site_main/
                                       django app with urls,models, etc...
```

In $HOME/.bashrc I have the following lines:

```
export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/.local/usr/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/projects/django:$HOME/projects/django/bw_python:$HOME/projects/django/bw_python/bw_python:$HOME/projects/django/bw_python/site_main:$PYTHONPATH
```

If I run python interpreter django and flup are working, manage.py runserver works without any errors.

Now in the public_html I have the following bw_python.fcgi script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, os
# Add a custom Python path.
sys.path.insert(0, "/home5/bwinnova/.local/lib/python")
# Switch to the directory of your project. (Optional.)
os.chdir("/home5/bwinnova/projects/django/bw_python")
# Set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable.
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "bw_python.settings"
from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

If I execute ./bw_python.fcgi I get:

```
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param REQUEST_METHOD required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_NAME required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!
Status: 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: http://localhost/home/
```

The .htaccess:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bw_python.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

The chmod on both of these files and including the $HOME/projects/django/bw_python is 755.
And sorry but from the tutorial I'm stuck here? What is the next step to be done? I always get a 500 server error and on the server error log it is only this:

```
[Fri Jul 27 19:29:14 2012] [warn] RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored.
```

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance from here.